# Scala XML with & in CDATA

Tags: xml, scala, cdata

I have some Scala XML template containing some JavaScript. I would like to use "&" in the JavaScript code. Scala converts it to:

```
&amp;
```

Any way of working around this problem. Here is an example:

```
                       ...      
            <script type="text/javascript">
              <![CDATA[

              function someFunction() {
                 var someId = $('#someId').val();
                 alert(someId == 'x' && someId == 'y')
              }
              ]]>
           </script>
                      ....
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `text`, like:

```
        val e = <script type="text/javascript">
          <![CDATA[

          function someFunction() {
             var someId = $('#someId').val();
             alert(someId == 'x' && someId == 'y')
          }
          ]]>
       </script>
       val script = e \\ "script" text
```

Output:

```
"
              function someFunction() {
                 var someId = $('#someId').val();
                 alert(someId == 'x' && someId == 'y')
              }
           "
```

Comment: Eventually the script generated should join another HTML template. When adding this fragment to the final HTML the "&" is still being escaped. Any way working around?